# Two external monitors on a Sony Vaio, no signal on one

Tags: sony-vaio, lg-monitor

I have a Sony Vaio PCG-71811M  connected to two LG LED 20M35 monitors.  One is hooked up with an VGA cable, which is running fine.  The other is connected with an HDMI to VGA adapter, which I cant seem to make work. Is there a way to have them run at the same time?  Do I need more hardware?

Comment: How are you converting HDMI to VGA?

Comment: its a cable i bought on amazon, HDMI to VGA. as the monitors only have VGA nd dvi INPUTS

Comment: Could you post a link to that cable?

Comment: sure, here it is.  http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00G9CITMY/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: damn. just read where it says . is wont convert.

Comment: can you recoment a cable that i can plug into my hdmi or usb and convert to VGA ?

Comment: HDMI-VGA conversion is hard if not impossible without active converters, because VGA is purely analog and HDMI is purely digital. You should rather try HDMI-DVI conversion, because DVI uses the same digital signal that HDMI does. They are quite cheap. Another thing is what Tetsujin pointed out in his answer: your GPU may be unable to support more screens. In that case you'll need an USB graphics adapter. Those aren't that cheap, offer low framerate and have significant impact on CPU load.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think that card can do 3 monitors; it was low-end when new - see http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-410m/specifications & http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu_list.php [hit the G3D button til the big numbers sort to the top] then ctrl/f for find & type 410m

Comment: so will i need to buy another video card ?

Comment: You'd need to check whether that's even possible. Lappies tend to be fairly fixed in form.

Comment: hope so , i´ve seen like 4 screens running from a laptop before..

Comment: it's possible to get a laptop GPU that's more than 10 times as powerful as the 410m...